# Wrapper with "margin: auto" gets pushed to left once it's filled with content

Tags: css, css-float

I've an empty document with only div named wrapper in it. it has margin: auto.

If I add more than, let's say, 15 lines of content to it, it get's pushed to left by about 10 - 9px. Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide us with an example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: (???) Could you show the code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it gets pushed left as soon as the scrollbar comes up on the right side of the viewport. `margin:auto` will keep the wrapper in the middle of its parent. Let's say your window is `800px` wide and the wrapper is `400px` wide, then it will have `200px` on each side of it because `margin:auto` will keep it in the middle. The you add content to your wrapper and this content makes the wrapper grow more than the height of your window. The scrollbar appears on the right and the window is still `800px`, but the viewport has become about 20 pixels less wide in order to show the scrollbar. As a result the total width of your page has shrunken to `780px` instead of `800px` and so the `margin:auto` will move your wrapper `10px` to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the div width. Also try `margin:0 auto;` instead of `margin:auto;`
See a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/TGyhS/1/